# Run macro(XLSB) using python

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I am facing the below error using python to call a macro from my macro workbook that contains all my macros and it's in XLSB extension
**Error:**
**FileNotFoundError: No such file:**

**Python code:**

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\1.Work\Automation\Personal All MAcro codes.xlsb')
your_macro = wb.macro('Iwebsite')
your_macro(1, 2)
```

Comment: Sounds like there is no such file. Double check the filepath carefully.

Comment: Hello BigBen, is it okay to use XLSB tho?

Comment: Sure, the code will work (if the path to your xlsb file is correct[ed])